# Django naming conventions for dates

Tags: django, naming-conventions

Is there any naming convention for "created" and "last edit" dates in Django?

ie. in Symfony Framework this fields are named by default:

- created_at
- updated_at

Comment: Since there's no official Django guideline about naming conventions, this should really be Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django origin models this fields are named based on Model type ie.

- auth.User: date_joined
- comments.Comment: submit_date

So probably we should follow this convention.

Comment: Actually this seems to be rather inconsistent. Why not have either `date_joined` and `date_submitted`, or `join_date` and `submit_date`?

Comment: In my opinion this isn't a convention, but an evidence that there is no convention.

Comment: Also, there is `last_login` in AbstractBaseUser (`django.contrib.auth.base_user`) which is even more inconsistent.

Answer (score 18):

Indeed, as far as I can tell there's no canonical convention for Django, but I really like the Rails convention (which I suppose also inspired Symphony):

- `created_at` for DateTime fields
- `created_on` for Date fields

`created` works fine for creation dates, but as soon as you have more ambiguous fields like `activated`, it becomes a problem. Is it a boolean or a date/datetime? Naming conventions exist to help developers understand code faster and waste less time with unimportant decisions. That's the philosophy behind the [Convention over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) paradigm, which is big in the Rails community but not as much in Django's unfortunately. This confusion I mentioned for example is typical and that's why I prefer to always be extra clear:

- If it's a boolean `is_activated`
- If it's datetime `activated_at`
- If it's just a date `activated_on`

I've heard people say that "you shouldn't mix field names with data types" but it seems like a rather empty tip in my opinion and I've never heard any concrete argument behind it. If we want to optimize code readability and decision making then I really think explicit naming conventions are the way to go.

Comment: Another way to look at it, is that it allows you to leverage dynamic typing. The meaning of the field remains the same, but the accuracy varies between 'yes', 'yes, on this day' and 'yes, on this day and that time'. 'No' and 'never' basically mean the same.

Comment: Actually Django has a lot of conventions (like the App convention of organizing code), but I believe "naming things" is out of scope of Django (PEP8 maybe?)

Comment: Sure, Django does have conventions, I'm not saying it doesn't. I'm just saying that the philosophy of defining and respecting conventions is not as important/explicit as in the Rails community, for example. I'm not sure this is in the scope of PEP8 because, as I perceive it, it's a problem that arrises mostly in the context of ORMs. In fact I'd say it's more of a Database problem than a Python one. But that's just an empirical observation, I'm not saying it's necessarily a DB issue in nature, but I think a DB convention is more urgent than one in the Python level in general…

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's something like a *canonical way* of naming such things in Django. Some parts are well covered by [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions), mostly because this sort of thing is *out of scope* of Django, since it's much more a matter of style (and maybe house conventions).

That said, I think it's pretty common to name these fields as `created_at` and `updated_at`, and I personally follow this convention when writing my own code. I advise to avoid names like `created` or `updated` since they're ambiguous (although some popular [libs](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model_extensions.html) use that style): are they booleans or something else? `is_created`/`is_updated`, if you need those, are better options.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `created` and `updated` without the `_at` suffix. I don't know of any "canonical" preference for naming the fields.

For what it is worth, I *think* Rails uses `created_at / created_on` and `updated_at / updated_on`.

Answer (score 0):

[Django Model Utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#timestampedmodel) has a model mixin for this, naming them `created` and `modified` -- I recommend using their model mixin to easily standardize across of your models and projects.